# Upgrade to 17.10 cinnamon windowing not working

Tags: 17.10, cinnamon

Just upgraded 17.04 => 17.10.  Booted into Unity, then installed cinnamon via the command line.  Logged out, then back into the cinnamon DE.  Appeared to work fine, but any interaction that creates a window, fails out.  For example, when I run cinnamon-settings:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 610, in <module>
window = MainWindow()
File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 188, in __init__
self.window = XApp.GtkWindow(visible=True, window_position=Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 139, in __getattr__
self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.XApp' object has no attribute 'GtkWindow'
```

or launching nemo:

```
nemo: symbol lookup error: nemo: undefined symbol: xapp_gtk_window_set_icon_name
```

I launched synaptic and installed a lot of the packages that are associated with cinnamon hoping the shotgun approach would work but it didn't.  I also removed and re-installed, no joy.  Looks like I'm missing some dependency in the gtk library, but I have no idea what it could be or how to install it.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Cinnamon but recently after upgrading my system I get this error when I tried to launch nemo

Here is how I fixed it:

```
sudo apt remove libxapp1
sudo apt remove xapps-common
sudo remove nemo*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo3
```

I also removed old nemo repo

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nemo
```

this is output of:

```
sudo apt policy nemo 
nemo:
  Installed: 3.6.4-1~webupd8~zesty01
  Candidate: 3.6.4-1~webupd8~zesty01
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.4-1~webupd8~zesty01 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.2-3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages
```